# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (48,64,3) into shape (0,1520,3)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

So, I am trying to use a small image to cover up the background.

```
background[top_left_height:top_left_height+height][top_left_width:top_left_width+width][:] = img
```

but I got the error message.

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (48,64,3) into shape (0,1520,3)

The code below shows the images I used.

```
background = cv2.imread("sample_data/background.jpg")
img = cv2.imread('sample_data/B1.jpg')
print(img.shape)
print(background.shape)
```

(48, 64, 3)

(720, 1520, 3)

Comment: You need `background[right_slices] = img`, where `right_slices` produce a (48,64,3) shape.  You can't chain indexing as you do.   Do that indexing step by step to see what I mean.  `background[top_left_height:top_left_height+height, top_left_width:top_left_width+width, :]` might be what you want - test it.

Comment: With `x=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)` compare `x[1:,2:]` and `x[1:][2:]`.  Look at `x[1:]` by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need a same slice of background image as the img shape.

something like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


background = cv2.imread("sample_data/background.jpg")
img = cv2.imread('sample_data/B1.jpg')
print(img.shape)
print(background.shape)

top_left_height = 0
top_left_width = 0
height = img.shape[0]
width = img.shape[1]

background[top_left_height:top_left_height+height, top_left_width:top_left_width+width] = img

cv2.imshow('img', background)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

this code inserts the img to the top-left corner of background image.